# immutable JS - immutable deep merge is overriding the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I am using Immutable JS in my node project to hold the very huge blob of map in the memory. Every key has an object as a value. Example:

```
const obj1 = {
  "foo.bar": {
     valid: ['baz']
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  "foo.bar": {
     key1: 'abc',
     key2: [1, 2, 3],
     valid: ['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
  }
}
```

expected Output for `const obj3 = Immutable.Map(obj2).mergeDeep(Immutable.Map(obj1))` is

```
"foo.bar": {
     key1: 'abc',
     key2: [1, 2, 3],

     valid: ['baz'] // here

  }
```

What i get is

```
"foo.bar": {
     valid: ['baz']
 }
```

I am using ImmutbaleJs 3.8.1.

Comment: The behavior changes if you run under 4.0.0-rc.9, you sure it's not just a bug? Although note that a deep merge would not dismiss the unmatched `valid` array elements; it's a *merge*. I would not have filed that issue so quickly, btw.

Comment: E.g., https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1452 regarding your expectation regarding the array (your expectation for the array merge is *not* what I would expect).

Comment: @DaveNewton. i think i am wrong with valid array. But what about the rest of the object? shouldn't it include key1 and key2?

Comment: @DaveNewton: 4.0.0-rc.9 is working as expected. but mergeDeepWith is not rendering the callback function instead it is concatenating list all the time. You see this behaviour here as well: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/mergeDeepWith

Comment: We need a "mergeDeepFromTop". It makes no sense to me that you can mergeDeep as long as the objects you want to merge are not top level.